# data wrangling in R with names_pattern for pivoting on ENDING pattern?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a column, CatSex, that's got data in it in a form similar to "American.Indian.or.Alaska.Native.men"--the characters after the last period, I want to turn into a new pivoted column, so I have two columns, one called Cat with only the demographic info in it, and one called Sex with the sex in it. The characters before the sex designation don't follow any clear pattern. I am not very good at R, but it's better than Tableau Prep with large data sets, it seems. What I ultimately want is to pivot the data so that I have two distinct columns for the different categories here. I used this code to get part of the way there (the original data held like 119 columns with names like "Grand.total.men..C2005_A_RV..First.major..Area..ethnic..cultural..and.gender.studies...Degrees.total"), but I can't figure out how to do this with the pattern I'm now left with in the column CatSex:

```
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(UnitID, Institution.Name), 
    names_to = c("CatSex", "Disc"), 
    names_pattern = "(.*)..C2005_A_RV..First.major..(.*)",
    values_to = "Count",
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  )
```

Here's a screenshot of the data structure I have now. I'm sorry for not putting in reproducible code--I don't know how to do that in this context!

[image]

EDIT: Here's a head(df) of the cleaned data so far:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  UnitID Institution.Name                        CatSex                   Disc                                                              Count
   <int> <fct>                                   <chr>                    <chr>                                                             <int>
1 177834 A T Still University of Health Sciences Grand.total.men          Health.professions.and.related.clinical.sciences...Degrees.total.   212
2 177834 A T Still University of Health Sciences Grand.total.women        Health.professions.and.related.clinical.sciences...Degrees.total.   359
3 177834 A T Still University of Health Sciences White.non.Hispanic.men   Health.professions.and.related.clinical.sciences...Degrees.total.   181
4 177834 A T Still University of Health Sciences White.non.Hispanic.women Health.professions.and.related.clinical.sciences...Degrees.total.   317
5 177834 A T Still University of Health Sciences Black.non.Hispanic.men   Health.professions.and.related.clinical.sciences...Degrees.total.     3
6 177834 A T Still University of Health Sciences Black.non.Hispanic.women Health.professions.and.related.clinical.sciences...Degrees.total.     5
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 3):

1. Using `extract` from `tidyr` package (it is in `tidyverse)`
2. Capture 2 groups with `()`
3. Define second group to have one or more characters that are not `.`  up to the end `$`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  extract(CatSex, c("Cat", "Sex"), "(.*)\\.([^.]+)$")
```

```
   UnitID             Institution.Name                              Cat   Sex
1  222178 Abilene Christian University                         Hispanic   men
2  222178 Abilene Christian University                         Hispanic women
3  222178 Abilene Christian University American.Indian.or.Alaska.Native   men
4  222178 Abilene Christian University American.Indian.or.Alaska.Native women
5  222178 Abilene Christian University        Asian.or.Pacific.Islander women
6  222178 Abilene Christian University        Asian.or.Pacific.Islander   men
7  222178 Abilene Christian University                      Grand.total   men
8  222178 Abilene Christian University                      Grand.total women
9  222178 Abilene Christian University               White.non.Hispanic   men
10 222178 Abilene Christian University               White.non.Hispanic women
11 222178 Abilene Christian University                lack.non.Hispanic   men
12 222178 Abilene Christian University               Black.non.Hispanic women
13 222178 Abilene Christian University                         Hispanic   men
14 222178 Abilene Christian University                         Hispanic women
15 222178 Abilene Christian University American.Indian.or.Alaska.Native   men
                                                   Disc
1        Communication journalism..and.related.programs
2         Communication journalism and.related.programs
3        Communication journalism..and.related.programs
4       Communication..journalism..and.related.programs
5       Communication..journalism..and.related.programs
6        Communication .journalism..and.related.program
7    Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.serv
8   computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.servi
9   Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.servi
10  Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.servi
11  Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.servi
12 Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.servi.
13   Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.serv
14 Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.servi.
15  Computer.and.information.sciences.and.support.servi
```

Comment: Thank you!! I might be able to figure other problems out from this. :)

Answer (score 1):

`pivot_longer` is not the right function in this context.

Here are few options -

1. Using `tidyr::separate`

```
tidyr::separate(df, 'CatSex', c('Cat', 'Sex'), sep = '(\\.)(?!.*\\.)')

#.                Cat   Sex
#1        Grand.total   men
#2        Grand.total women
#3 White.non.Hispanic   men
#4 White.non.Hispanic women
#5 Black.non.Hispanic   men
#6 Black.non.Hispanic women
```

2. Using `stringr` functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  mutate(Sex = str_extract(CatSex, 'men|women'), 
         Cat = str_remove(CatSex, '\\.(men|women)'))
```

3. In base R

```
transform(df, Sex = sub('.*\\.(men|women)', '\\1', CatSex), 
              Cat = sub('\\.(men|women)', '', CatSex))
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- data.frame(CatSex = c("Grand.total.men", "Grand.total.women", 
"White.non.Hispanic.men", "White.non.Hispanic.women", 
"Black.non.Hispanic.men", "Black.non.Hispanic.women"))
```